# UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout methods never called

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionView` which lies upon a `UITableViewCell`. The cell is the delegate and datasource for the collection view. Everything is setup in a storyboard. The cell implements `numberOfItemsInSection` and `cellForItemAtIndexPath` methods and these methods are always called successfully. Also the cell implements methods from `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol such as `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`. And these methods are never called. What may be a possible reason for that?

```
class SignUpFollowCategoriesCell : UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{

@IBOutlet weak var categoryCollection: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var categoryLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var followButton: UIButton!

func setChosen(chosen:Bool)
{
    followButton.checked = chosen
}

var category:Category?
{
    didSet
    {
        guard let confirmedFollowButton = self.followButton else
        {
            return
        }
        confirmedFollowButton.hidden = true
        guard let category = self.category else
        {
            return
        }
        guard let controller = self.controller else
        {
            return
        }
        guard let sites = controller.allSites[category.id] else
        {
            return
        }
        confirmedFollowButton.hidden = sites.count == 0
    }

}
weak var controller:SignUpFollowCategoriesController?

func setupWithController(control:SignUpFollowCategoriesController)
{
    controller = control
    guard let tmp = followButton else
    {
        return
    }
    tmp.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SignUpFollowCategoriesCell.clicked), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    followButton.setStyleOptions(false, style: .ClearBackground,  title: "+ Follow All")
    followButton.setStyleOptions(true, style: .YellowBackground,  title: "Following")

}

func clicked()
{
    guard let control = controller else
    {
        return
    }
    guard let cat = category else
    {
        return
    }
    if control.categoryIsChosen(cat)
    {
        self.setChosen(false)
        control.unfollowCategory(cat)
    }else
    {
        self.setChosen(true)
        control.followCategory(cat)
    }
    categoryCollection.reloadData()

}

private func updateFollowBtnStyle()
{
    guard let control = controller else
    {
        return
    }
    guard let cat = category else
    {
        return
    }
    if control.categoryIsChosen(cat)
    {
        self.setChosen(true)
    }else
    {
        self.setChosen(false)
    }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if let tmp = self.category
    {
        if let sites = controller?.allSites[tmp.id]
        {
            return sites.count
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


private func firstLetterCaps(str : String) -> String
{
    var ret = str
    ret.replaceRange(str.startIndex...str.startIndex, with: String(str[str.startIndex]).capitalizedString)
    return ret
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{

    if let cell:SignupCategorySiteCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("SignUpCategoryCollectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? SignupCategorySiteCell
    {
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage.imageWithColor(UIColor.slangBlueLight())
        var slangSite : SlangSite?

        if let tmpID = self.category?.id
        {
            let sites = controller?.allSites[tmpID]

            if let site = sites![indexPath.row] as SlangSite?
            {
                if let url = site.details.siteProfileImageURL()
                {
                    cell.imageView.af_setImageWithURL(url)
                }

                let siteName = firstLetterCaps(site.details.siteName)
                cell.siteNameLabel.text = siteName

                slangSite = site
            }
        }
        if let control = controller,let site = slangSite
        {
            if control.siteIsChosen(site)
            {
                cell.followStyle()
            }
            else
            {
                cell.unfollowStyle()
            }
        }
        cell.onCellClickedBlock = {[weak self,controller] in
            if let site = slangSite, let control = controller
            {
                if control.siteIsChosen(site)
                {
                    cell.unfollowStyle()
                    control.unfollowSite(site)
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.followStyle()
                    control.followSite(site)
                }
                self?.updateFollowBtnStyle()
            }
        }
        return cell
    } else
    {
        collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "DebugCell")
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("DebugCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        return cell
    }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                             sizeForItemAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSizeMake(92, 112)
}

func collectionView( collectionView: UICollectionView,
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                             insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero
}

func collectionView( collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100.0
}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide code?

Comment: @EmrahAkgül sure. what code exactly you would like to see?

Comment: Your custom TableViewCell class.

Comment: @EmrahAkgül here it is

Comment: You need to instantiate a flowLayout programmatically and set it to your custom collection view's custom flow layout. Probable pseudo code for is that:     self.categoryCollection.flowLayout = your instantiated flow layout

Comment: @EmrahAkgul 1) i tried that. it didn't work 2) it is not required. check the project from here https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started . it has setup just like in my case but there it works

Comment: According to link you provided, you haven't created an extension for UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.  Look at the below of the  line which starts with "Next, add the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout"

Comment: @EmrahAkgül but how can that make a difference?

Comment: I'll try that now but it is unlikely it can help

Comment: @EmrahAkgül just tried using extension. it didn't work unfortunately

Comment: I have no answer why it would help, but it is a good idea to finish a tutorial to see its entire effects.

Comment: @EmrahAkgül thanks buddy for your attempt to help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127891/discussion-between-emrah-akgul-and-andrey-chernukha).

Comment: did you try validating the collectionViewLayout?

Comment: @Joe sorry, I don't understand what you're talking about

Comment: @AndreyChernukha I think you have to set delegate of flowLayout in storyboard or programatically.

Comment: @SunilChauhan you are wrong. This is an excerpt from the documentation: "A flow layout works with the collection view’s delegate object to determine the size of items, headers, and footers in each section and grid. That delegate object must conform to the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol. Use of the delegate allows you to adjust layout information dynamically"

Comment: Ah, right. @AndreyChernukha Check method name according to the swift version: `public func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize` =======> `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: try this `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 00
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 100
        layout.invalidateLayout()
    
        return CGSize(width: (92), height:(112))
    }`

Comment: @SunilChauhan it is correct. The problem was that the method name was from a different Swift version. If you make it an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check method name according to the swift version:

```
public func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
```

=======> sizeForItemAtIndexPath